# How do I manually compile angular directives on page loaded outside angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am converting a JS only SPA to Angular. When the path to a particular page or partial is only navigated through Angular, everything works fine. However, if I load a partial with Angular directives from the old code, the directives do not compile.

Eventually, the application will be Angular. Until then, I have a requirement to function in a mixed mode.

How can I use the old, non-Angular code to compile the directives on the pages they are loading?

Comment: Given this is an anti-pattern (do not load template information from outside angular), I have figured out a way to start angular from the top of the app and build out the functionality I need from there. Thanks for checking in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the issue is that the `ng-app` attribute isn't included in your partials or in the HTML where the partials are included. IIRC that attribute is what triggers the compilation. Can you add that attribute to, say, your `BODY` element or in the partials?

Comment: I'm bootstrapping to the document. The application is loading fine. ng-inspector shows the scope I need to run in. However, my ng-click tags are not active b/c they are being loaded by a different process and perhaps not compiled. I've been trying $scope.$apply(). I can get the $scope object from the external JS. However, calling $apply() is undefined. If I refresh the page once the directives are on the DOM, they run.

Comment: In that case, you'll have to post enough code so that I/others can see or replicate the problem.

Comment: given this is an anti-pattern (do not load template information from outside angular), I have figured out a way to start angular from the top of the app and build out the functionality I need from there. Thanks for checking in.